# Resolving entities while parsing xml file in nodejs

Tags: xml, node.js

My xml file has

```
<!DOCTYPE application [<!ENTITY % common  SYSTEM "../common.ent">
%common;]>
```

and i have used `&commonFaults;`, (which is one of the entities defined in `./common.ent` file), many where in the xml file

in my node application i want to input the stringifed xml file content.
and in return i want all the entities to be resolved.

input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!DOCTYPE application [<!ENTITY % common  SYSTEM "../common.ent">
    %common;]>
    <application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
        <grammars>
            <include href="../xsd/api.xsd"/>
            <include href="../xsd/api-common.xsd"/>
        </grammars>
        <method name="GET" id="listVersionsv2">
             &commonFaults;
        </method>
    </application>
```

common.ent file :

```
 <!ENTITY commonFaults
           '
        <response status="503" xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
            <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="csapi:serviceUnavailable"/>
            <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
        <response status="400" xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
            <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="csapi:badRequest"/>
            <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
           '>
```

Desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!DOCTYPE application [<!ENTITY % common  SYSTEM "../common.ent">
    %common;]>
    <application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
        <grammars>
            <include href="../xsd/api.xsd"/>
            <include href="../xsd/api-common.xsd"/>
        </grammars>
        <method name="GET" id="listVersionsv2">
        <response status="503" xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
            <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="csapi:serviceUnavailable"/>
            <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
        <response status="400" xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
            <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="csapi:badRequest"/>
            <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
        </method>
    </application>
```

I search `xmllint` with `--noent` option which does this efficiently.

I am looking for a similar lib/tool which does this as npm module, which i can 'require' in node application and accomplish the same task as `xmllint` does.

I Do not want to use ChildProcess of node.