# How to use regex to find all xml entities in a multi line string

Tags: regex, xml, parsing

i am trying to parse an xml entity file to get all the entities using regex.

here is what i have done http://regex101.com/r/kU4lN8/1
EDITed link : http://regex101.com/r/tF4kY9/1

This encloses entities to any other attribute which ends with '>'.

Any help on to get the entities?

This is my desired result of matches

```
<!ENTITY % common  SYSTEM "../common.ent">
```

.

```
<!ENTITY commonFaults
           '
        <response xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
            <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="csapi:computeFault"/>
            <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
        <response status="503" xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
            <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="csapi:serviceUnavailable"/>
            <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
        <response status="400" xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
            <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="csapi:badRequest"/>
            <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
        <response status="401" xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
            <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="csapi:unauthorized"/>
            <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
        <response status="403" xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
            <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="csapi:forbidden"/>
            <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
        <response status="405" xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
            <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="csapi:badMethod"/>
            <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
        <response status="413" xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
            <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="csapi:overLimit"/>
            <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
        </response>
           '>
```

.....
..
..
.

```
<!ENTITY DELETE '<command xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">DELETE</command>'>
```

Comment: here is my main goal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200200/resolving-entities-while-parsing-xml-file-in-nodejs

Comment: i want to get all the entities from an entities file which i can input as stringified content

Comment: Why don't you try xml parsers?

Comment: i have gone through xmllint but that is command line tool. i dont want to use child process in my node app

Comment: in npm modules i have gone through xml2js/sax parser but that do not handle <!DOCTYPE and they give error while parsing

Comment: You're using a hammer to drive in a screw. Use an XML parser.

Comment: agree with you but can you suggest me some alternative that comes with npm module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
<!ENTITY\s+(\S+)\s+'([^']*)'\s*>
```

It uses character classes to delimit parts you are interested by:

- `\S+` for the entity name *(all that is not a whitespace)*
- `[^']+` for the content *(all that is not a simple quote)*

For this pattern, the modifier s *(that doesn't exist in javascript)* is not needed.

The entity name and the content are stored in capture groups.

Comment: right move but i need little bit more regex should match this as well <!ENTITY % common  SYSTEM "../common.ent">

Comment: @Koka:In this case, use the same idea and adapt it, it's not difficult.

Comment: here is the new link http://regex101.com/r/tF4kY9/1   I know i deviated from the question asked. but that is actually required.